# Callback for connected/unconnected device using portaudio?

Tags: c++, audio, portaudio

Is there a callback to know when the device list is updated?

If not, is there a way of detecting it ( ideally cross platform )?

At the moment the only way i found is to re-initialise PortAudio.

ps:
I tried to find "callbacks" documentation on PortAudio documentation but i failed to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a callback to know when the device list is updated?

Not in the main line code. There is a branch supporting this functionality on some platforms. New contributors are always welcome to help out finish this. It is a much-needed feature.

Note that the device list is *never* updated between calls to `Pa_Initialize()` and `Pa_Terminate()`. This is a basic invariant of the API. The branch also supports a `refresh` call.

The way to do it with the current version is to use platform-specific checks, then call `Pa_Terminate();Pa_Initialize();` as you suggest.

Comment: we implemented terminate/initialize and it was fast enough!

Answer (score 1):

If your OS is Linux, you can use the inotify() system call, and watch the /dev directory, or subdirectory.  I don't know about Windows, though.

Comment: good to know! might be the case of finding out how it works on each OS and then just have a classic "switch" :P